# Is there a command to select everything between a range of cursors in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

My circumstance:

I'm working with Fortran. Sometimes, I want to select everything that's within a block of code. It's easy for me to select the start/end elements of a block because it all look like this:

```
SUBROUTINE FOO(BAR)
IF (BAR .GT. 1) THEN
    //DO SOMETHING
ENDIF
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE FOO
```

Move the cursor to `SUBROUTINE`, Hit `Ctrl+D` twice, done. Both instances of the `SUBROUTINE` keyword are highlighted.

But now I want to select everything *between* the `SUBROUTINE` keywords. I want a selection that includes everything from the start of the first `SUBROUTINE` to the end of the second `SUBROUTINE`. I prefer this be done in language agnostic manner, because I can imagine circumstances like this might occur in other contexts and I don't want to bother accumulating muscle memory for something that only works in Fortran.

Is there a command in sublime to select all text that occurs between the start and end positions of a multicursor selection?

Comment: I think there is not a command that do it. A plugin can surely be made that selects from the min selected position to the max selected position

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about making a plugin. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't some native command I was missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a group of commands in sublime that approximate this behavior. They're exposed through the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> combo keys:

- set_mark, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
- select_to_mark, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- delete_to_mark, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Search for the first result, call set_mark, search for the second, call select_to_mark.

Comment: Perfect! Easy was to delete a few million lines.